# @font-face, what is the point of providing multiple options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css, ruby-on-rails-4

For example, I've seen designers do things like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ProximaNovaRegular';
  src: url("<%= font_path('PrimaNova-Regular.otf') %>");
  src: url("<%= font_path('PrimaNova-Regular.otf') %>") format("opentype"),
  url("<%= font_path('proximanova-regular-webfont.woff') %>") format('woff'),
  url("<%= font_path('proximanova-regular-webfont.ttf') %>") format('truetype'),
  url("<%= font_path('proximanova-regular-webfont.svg#ProximaNovaRegular') %>") format('svg');
}
```

What is the purpose of having several different formats? Would just one suffice? I'm in the process of adding a font using @font-face to my app, however I only have the .otf format - is that okay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different types are for cross-browser compatibility. Even the order of the types is important for some browsers.

Check out [Bulletproof @font-face Syntax](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/) and [How to use CSS @font-face](http://nicewebtype.com/notes/2009/10/30/how-to-use-css-font-face/).

To convert your fonts and get CSS file with the right syntax you can use [Font Squirrel - Webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator).

Answer (score 0):

In 2010-era browsers,

Cross-Browser Compatibility

Internet Explorer only supports EOT

Mozilla browsers support OTF and TTF

Safari and Opera support OTF,

TTF and SVG  Chrome supports TTF and SVG.

From http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/